# Open Browser when we click the app form start menu with hidden footer and header

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make an app which can automatically open a URL when we click the installed app icon on our android phone, and the browser which opens up its header and footer should be hidden like we are viewing a full screen page,,, kindly help please

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.it"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

While if you want to show your site inside your activity you should use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component

Comment: where is have to type this? i mean in which directory? Under SRC or BIN ?

Comment: It will be very kind if you if u just send me a pdf link or some video link or any site link where i can learn particularly thing what i m trying to do here

Comment: It is very basically. You need an Activity, in which you define an onclicklistener on you button and inside your onClick method insert the code lines I suggest you! Try following this basic guide: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html

Comment: which button? i mean i dont want to create any UI for the app i just want that, whenever i click on the app icon from my android phone instead of any UI directly a web page gets open.

Comment: you can create an activity using this description android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" in Manifest and in the  onCreate you can execute the code that I suggest you.
Or you can create a Service.

Comment: ok sir i have made this change in manifest and its working,, on my android device as no display is shown but the app does work in the background,, now how to pass a browser launch activity (with a specific UR)L to directly open browser of android.

Comment: nserting in your onCreate method the browserIntent of my answer. Then you can call finish method for finishing your application.

Comment: can u just create an oncreate method for me and then insert the browsertintent so that i can past it into the the main,java file

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(yourURL));
   startActivity(browserIntent);
         finish();
     }

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Intent cannot be resolved to a type
 - Intent cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 - Uri cannot be resolved
 - Intent cannot be resolved to a type
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
  ClassInstanceCreationExpression 
error in intent browserintnt line

Comment: Yes, you must include the library. Use the line import android.content.Intent;

Comment: Its done sir its working but its not opening the default browser of android but opening mozilla firefox,, anyway it can open default android browser

Comment: Sir ok i have changed the default browser but now i need to hide the web browser's headers footers etc, so that when it opened through app it shouldn't look like that you are working on a browser hiding the headers and footers will give it a full screen experience

Comment: from the best of my knowledge you can't tell the browser to set automatically full screen. If you need this you should use an Activity, create a simple webView and then load the webpage inside it. Look here: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: Try adding this in the manifest, : android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: tried it Just but no use,, still that url address bar of browser is appearing on top

Comment: I'm sorry @Abhimanyu, I don't know other solutions. I can let you with this last suggestion: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2008/09/using-webviews.html

Comment: Sir, no use,, but if i wana go the other way i.e. making app via html 5 and java script so can it help to achieve what i want to.. if yes then can u send me a good guide to learn app making in java script and HTML

Comment: sir i made some changes and now the app is not even working properly, error is in activity main xml file i guess, Its like this only

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    
/>

Comment: In your activity try: setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
 
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl("yourWebsite");

And then in your Manifest declare the activity

Comment: it should be decared under protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState), right? and one more thing in my manifest how to declare the activty its already like android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:name="com.nava.MainActivity"

Comment: Yes. In manifest you need: <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:name="com.examle.WebActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
  </activity>

Where instead of example.com you need to insert the "path" of your activity

Comment: when typing the public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
 setContentView(R.layout.web_view); 
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
 webView.loadUrl("www.yahoo.com");
} 
 error occur is Multiple markers at this line
 - webView cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - webView1 cannot be resolved or is not 
  a field
 - WebView cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: anyways i have figured to sort it out,, but still problem resides abhot hiding the addressbar